# How to deploy the project on Google App Engine by preserving the changes of other developers?

Tags: google-app-engine

Till now I was working alone on a project on Google App Engine. So I had to write the code and upload it on App Engine using `gcloud app deploy project-path/app.yaml`.

But now a bigger project has arrived. So a team has to work on it and everyone has their own systems. I simply want to ask how can we deploy project from different devices still preserving the changes made by other developers?  As everyone has to deploy their code on cloud for the same project. I searched over the web but found nothing. Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this article will help you. It describes how to deploy from Gitlab to Google App Engine

https://medium.com/evenbit/an-easy-guide-to-automatically-deploy-your-google-app-engine-project-with-gitlab-ci-48cb84757125

Regards

Michael

Comment: I think this is the only option that I can do... Thanks for support :)